# C# drag a snapping control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a form that when a panel is dragged from a parent panel to another panel, the new panel becomes the parent. I created a version of the program, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. How would I add a timer to the dragged panel it so that it doesn't move immediately after clicking it, and properly create snapping bounds so that it snaps within a certain distance around the parent panel.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SNAPtest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Point MousePoint = new Point();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel_white.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(White_MouseDown);
            panel_white.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(White_MouseMove);
        }

        private void White_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                int mx = Math.Min(Math.Max(panel_white.Location.X - MousePoint.X + e.X, 0), panel_white.Parent.Width - panel_white.Width);
                int my = Math.Min(Math.Max(panel_white.Location.Y - MousePoint.Y + e.Y, 0), panel_white.Parent.Height - panel_white.Height);
                panel_white.Location = new Point(mx, my);
            }

            if (panel_white.Location.X == Math.Max(panel_maroon.Location.X, 10) | panel_white.Location.Y == Math.Max(panel_maroon.Location.Y, 100))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Maroon has focus");
                panel_white.Parent = panel_maroon;
            }

            if (panel_white.Location.X == Math.Max(panel_blue.Location.X, 10) | panel_white.Location.Y == Math.Max(panel_blue.Location.Y, 100))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blue has focus");
                panel_white.Parent = panel_blue;
            }
        }

        private void White_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            panel_white.Parent = this;
            panel_white.BringToFront();
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                MousePoint = e.Location;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking questions in C# related to UI, please make sure to include the appropriate UI Framework tags (`winforms`, `wpf`, `asp.net-mvc`, etc.) as C# does not (in and of itself) contain any UI frameworks.